# PHP - Insert values into database specific to each user in a HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't really know the best way to word this so I'll try my best to describe what I'm trying to achieve.
I have a table within a form like so

```
<form action="manager-match-report-run.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" name="registerForm">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Goals</th>
                    <th>Assists</th>
                    <th>Match Rating</th>
                    <th hidden>playerId</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $sql_players = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE teamId = '$teamId' AND selected = '1'";
                    $res_players = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_players);

                    while($row_players = $res_players->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row_players["firstName"]. "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row_players["lastName"]. "</td>";
                        echo "<td><div class='form-group'><input name='goals' class='form-control py-4' type='number'/></div></td>";
                        echo "<td><div class='form-group'><input name='assists' class='form-control py-4' type='number'/></div></td>";
                        echo "<td><div class='form-group'><input name='matchRating' class='form-control py-4' type='number' step='0.01' min='0' max='10'/></div></td>"
                    ?>
                    <td hidden><input name="playerId" value="<?php echo $row_players['playerId'];?>"></td>
                    <?php echo "</tr>";
                    }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0"><button id="manager-report-btn" onclick="return confirmReport()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="manager-report">Confirm Report</button></div>
    </form>
```

[image: form]

I'm looking for the correct way to insert the data into the correct rows in the Player table. e.g. Update the Player table so Alison has 5 goals, 1 assist, 8 match rating, Ben has 0 goals, 1 assist, 7 match rating etc.

I'm assuming I'd have to use a loop of some sorts but have had no luck so far so any help or advice would be great, thank you :)

Comment: You would use `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah I'm aware of that, but what would be the correct way to loop through each player in the table and update their row accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs all have the same name, so only the last value gets posted to your app.

Add a dynamic name for each control, for example instead of `name='matchRating'`, use

```
$playerName = htmlentities($playername);
$inputname = sprintf("matchRating[%s]", $playerName);
printf("<input name=\"%s\" type=\"text\"/>", $inputname);
```

When the form is submitted, you get the data in an array, which you can loop over to update your database records:

```
$matchRatings = $_GET["matchRating"];
foreach ($matchRatings as $playerName => $rating) {
   // Update player rating in database
   // Important: Do not forget to guard against SQL injection!
   $sql = sprintf("update MYTABLE set MATCHRATING=%d where PLAYERNAME='%s'", $rating, $playerName);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much